# why i get a GET response instead a POST when i realize a api call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, e-commerce, marketplace

when I make a `POST` request in postman I see that the json is not sent to me and nothing is created but return a status: `200`, if I look at the logs I see that this request is registered as `GET`, I don't understand this behavior, in other applications with the same configuration this does not happen,I don't know if the problem comes from the `nginx / apache` server or the `rails server`

here the plesk log:

[image]

this is my body test request

```
{
  "event_id": "fd193bc1-992f-4e51-bb28-b841417f68a9",
  "order_id": "61e2d090-0d53-451f-9031-413559d34732",
  "order_number": "10103211120218",
  "state": "fulfilled",
  "store_id": "11",
  "timestamp": "2021-06-03T12:06:02.576Z",
  "delivery_details": {
     "delivery_tracking_number": "003404342888680268172",
     "delivery_carrier_name": "DHL",
     "return_tracking_number": "35141263178",
     "return_carrier_name": "DHL"
  },
  "customer_billing_address": {
    "first_name": "Max",
    "last_name": "Mustermann",
    "address_line_1": "Musterstraße 12 34",
    "zip_code": "12345",
    "city": "Berlin",
    "country_code": "DE"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "item_id": "15c3aa83-3f73-4ad6-a326-e1a10a89dd52",
      "ean": "4059701022541",
      "price": 99.95,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "article_number": "31.832.34-6,5",
      "zalando_article_number": "GA111N0JN-J110065000",
      "article_location": "213"
    },
    {
      "item_id": "101610aa-71b1-4f52-b3ab-4d6cbc4e8adb",
      "ean": "4059701214472",
      "price": 99.95,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "article_number": "33.731.54-7",
      "zalando_article_number": "GA111N0JE-J110007000",
      "article_location": "213"
    }
  ]
}
```

the endpoint is `https://www.somedomain.com/api/v1/orders/zalando`

and the routes:
`zalando_api_v1_orders POST           /api/v1/orders/zalando(.:format)                                  api/v1/orders#zalando {:format=>:json}`

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :orders, only: [:index, :show, :update, :options] do 
      post 'zalando', on: :collection
    end
  end
end
```

and this is the class method with which I create the orders with what it should receive in the response

```
def call 
  if Order.where(order_code: [order_code_with_store,order_code]).any?
    success
  else 
    order = Order.create(order_params)
    items = OrderItem.create(order_item_params(order.id))

    if order.persisted? && items.all? { | item| item.persisted? }
      UserMailer.marketplace_order_admin(order).deliver
      success
    else 
      success
    end
  end
rescue 
  order&.destroy
  success
end
```

Comment: @dbugger routes added, I hope to provide some more info. Thank you

Comment: What does postman show exactly? Neither code nor routes will help, as the problem occurs before your request hits the application

Comment: @BroiSatse shows nothing at all to the postman, just status 200 in green, but nothing else, no body, no warnings, no errors, and when I go to look at the log I noticed a GET request like the one in the picture

Comment: Are you sure Postman is sending a POST request. seems unlikely if the server is receiving it as GET? Also does your `show` have a similar rescue statement? That `rescue` is masking any issue that might occur in `call` because it is rescuing every `StandardError` no matter what. (DO NOT DO THIS)

Comment: @cisco - Can you see the request in postamn?